# Moving turtles towards two different colors of the patch in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I have a basic NetLogo question.

I would like to encode the following:

1. The turtle asks what color the patch is in if it is green, it can walk on the green patches.

I know it is a basic question of NetLogo. But, I'm trying and some errors appear, such as: MOVE-TO expected input to be an agent but got NOBODY instead

Could someone help me understand what I am wrong with, or give any suggestions or even models that do this for me to explore? Every help is welcome. Thanks

```
globals [ edge-size ]

to setup
    clear-all
      set edge-size 10
      set-patch-size 20
      let pcolors []
      set pcolors [135 55 105 85]
      ask patches [
        set pcolor item (random 4) colors
        ]
      crt 1 [
        set size 1
        set color black
        ;pen-down
        ]
     reset-ticks
     end

  to go
   ask turtles [
    if pcolor = green ;; if own pcolor patch = green
     [ move-to one-of patches with [ pcolor = "green" ] ]    
 end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code `move-to [ veg ] of patch-under-me` suggests you have several fundamental misunderstandings about how NetLogo thinks. I recommend that you do some more of the tutorials and look at the Model Library built in to NetLogo to find models that are similar to what you want to do. You also need to build in much smaller pieces and get a piece working properly before moving to the next piece.

What is wrong with `move-to [ veg ] of patch-under-me`?

1. `[ veg ] of patch-under-me` is a variable with values like pink or green. So you are saying 'move to green'
2. What's more, the colour that it gives back is the colour where the turtle is standing now, not where you want it to go to

You probably want something more like:

```
move-to one-of patches with [veg = "green"]
```

So go back to basics. Have just two colours (say red and blue) and move turtles around trying to get onto a red patch. Make that work before doing anything else. Now have only a few red patches, does your code still work? Then you can start adding a bunch of different conditions and colours

Comment: I use ask turtles [ move-to one-of patches with [pcolor = "green"] and this error appeared: MOVE-TO expected input to be an agent but got NOBODY instead.

Comment: that's because "green" is a text string, not a colour and `pcolor` is a colour. I used the variable name 'veg' in the example code. If you have dropped that then `move-to one-of patches with [pcolor = green]`

Comment: Thanks a lot JenB